# Verify object class

Tags: php, class

I am trying to verify if function did insert into database and return message..

class.php

```
<?php 
class Database {
    var $host="localhost";
    var $user="root";
    var $pass="";
    var $db="vjezba";

    public function spajanje() {
        $con=mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->db); 
        return $con;
    }
    public function napravi_insert($imeTablice,$ime,$prezime) {
        $conn=$this->spajanje();
        mysqli_query($conn,"insert into $imeTablice values('','".$ime."','".$prezime."')");
    }
}
```

index.php

```
    <?php 
    include "klase.php";

    $radnja = new Database();
    //use extract method so no need to call $_POST again and again
    extract($_POST);

    if(isset($save)) {
        $imeTablice = "admin2";
        $radnja->napravi_insert($imeTablice,$ime,$prezime);
        //echo "Done!";

/* I am trying to make something like this */
        if($radnja->napravi_insert == TRUE) {
            echo "Done!";
        } else {
            echo "Error!";
        }
/* // / / / // */

    }
```

How I can make objects into variables and test if it is "success" or error?

Comment: Since release of php 5.0.0 (in **2004**), you should not be using `var` keyword. Your tutorial might be slightly ancient. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @tereško okay, what do you suggest instead of var keyword?

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php ... also, as a side-note (your really should write code in english): http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/08/21/the-story-of-a-coder-who-doesnt-speak-english/

Comment: @tereško Thanks. Nice story, I will do it ( first I am trying to type in Croatian language because of understanding of OOP. ) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First return query status from `napravi_insert` method

```
public function napravi_insert($imeTablice,$ime,$prezime) {
    $conn=$this->spajanje();
    return mysqli_query($conn,"insert into $imeTablice values('','".$ime."','".$prezime."')");
}
```

Then compare the return value of `napravi_insert` method

```
$insert_status = $radnja->napravi_insert($imeTablice,$ime,$prezime);
if($insert_status == TRUE) {
    echo "Done!";
} else {
   echo "Error!";
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks I did it like this. :)

Comment: do I need `return $insert_status;` after verifying?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the result of the `msqli_query` function:

```
public function napravi_insert($imeTablice,$ime,$prezime) {
    $conn=$this->spajanje();
    $insert_state = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into $imeTablice values('','".$ime."','".$prezime."')");
    return $insert_state !== false;
}
```

---

So your code looks like the following:

**class.php**

```
<?php 
class Database {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "";
    private $db = "vjezba";

    public function spajanje() {
        return mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
    }

    public function napravi_insert($imeTablice, $ime, $prezime) {
        $conn = $this->spajanje();
        $insert_state = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO $imeTablice VALUES ('','".$ime."','".$prezime."')");
        return $insert_state !== false;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
include "klase.php";

$radnja = new Database();

//use extract method so no need to call $_POST again and again
extract($_POST);

if(isset($save)) {
    $imeTablice = "admin2";

    if($radnja->napravi_insert($imeTablice, $ime, $prezime) === true) {
        echo "Done!";
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to accept 2 answers, I did it like @MH2K9 answer, because I think it will be great idea set all into function :) Thanks anyway